# Html code <li> in textfield: issue with long text

Tags: html, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I try to print some text formatted with html code in a field in *JasperReports* report.

Sample:

```
<ul><li>some looooooooooooooooooooooong text</li></ul>
```

but if the text is too long for one line, it generates a second one but it starts at the beginning which is wrong.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

[image: text starts at the beginning of the line which is wrong]

Comment: use `margin:0px` and `padding:0px` for your `Ul` and `li` and make a fiddle for it

Comment: @Thomas- Did you get solution/workaround of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is some style sheet (not disclosed in the question) that causes the list formatting to put the list bullet “inside” a list item. It is a setting like `ul { list-style-position: inside }` somewhere. Either remove it, or override it with the CSS rule

```
ul { list-style-position: outside }
```

You may need to use a more specific selector or, as the last resort, the `!important` specifier to make your rule “win” in the CSS cascade.